# Encrypt secret manager value using kms cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager, amazon-kms

How I encrypt secret manager value in aws kms so that no on can see the plain text value . it basically should be decrypted in lambda using kms . is this even possible in AWS .

I could see that we can use kms to encrypt and decrypt kms values, but that happens at rest .

Comment: You encrypt it before you use it cloudformation.

Comment: but CloudFormation is the one which would be creating resources . how can I encrypt and save as encrypted value for environment variable .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use lambda to either access or store data in cloud formation dynamically, you likely want to use a lambda-backed custom resource.  Read more about it here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html.

Basically, you can either pass data to the lambda function (which can be dynamic based on outputs of resources already created) and/or get dynamic data that it created through its outputs.

However, secret manager is designed to be able to let authorized users/entities (like EC2 instances, for example) to see the plaintext password.  Consider instead setting up which users/entities are allowed to use.  See here for more detail on access control to secret manager: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/auth-and-access_determining-access.html

Answer (score 0):

To encrypt a given plaintext secret for inclusion within a CloudFormation template, you can use the [custom secret provider](https://github.com/binxio/cfn-secret-provider). It will decrypt the secret and store it in the SSM parameter store, as shown below:

```yaml
Resources:
ApiKey:
  Type: Custom::Secret
  Properties:
    Name: /datadog/api-key
    EncryptedContent: >-
      AQICAHgefwksukJYA7L2AkPMZLGjZsGxHbvY9AoVs55dcju1AwEZui/8lNbnGAhv63Wh0heUAAAA3zCB
      3AYJKoZIhvcNAQcGoIHOMIHLAgEAMIHFBgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwHgYJYIZIAWUDBAEuMBEEDOXKKVZ4ft75
      /oZ2TQIBEICBlzf5j1M3w6OH+iphx59kFLnNoKb+u1RCLfIqEitrt6VGu13/jDlnDcPE2DfkZFkW3fnm
      Nn5OXfgt1L9j4XYdIQTEwexorNqUr5pUtMfS9YX8yL9DbArH+XBv/OQPSj8VsuWRcwFP5EwZKB9O4X3l
      1pZlPafp2Y/ndWXgC1o6YgfplnmjufoUUTy8wi4P5glbwnqGP/iyc7g=
    ReturnSecret: true
    RefreshOnUpdate: true
    ServiceToken: !Sub 'arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:binxio-cfn-secret-provider'
```

The value is stored encrypted, but will be available in plaintext from the parameter store for those authorised to read it. By specifying `ReturnSecret`, you can access the plaintext secret in the CloudFormation template itself.

If it is a static secret, storing the secret in the parameter store is way cheaper.

For a more information checkout https://binx.io/blog/2018/10/21/encrypting-secrets-in-aws-cloudformation/